# Как сделать так, чтобы бот в тг писал через ваш аккаунт

Tags: python

Я хочу создать бота и подключить его к своему аккаунту в тг, чтобы он анализировал группы, в которых я состою. В чатах помимо спама бывает нужная инфа, поэтому я хочу чтобы бот проверял каждое сообщение в определенных чатах на ключевые слова (я напишу список ключевых слов, алгоритм для анализа текста у меня есть). Но добавлять бота в каналы запрещено, поэтому мне нужно, чтобы этот бот сидел от моего аккаунта и получал сообщения через мой аккаунт. Как это сделать? Большинство статей предлагают решения только через добавления бота в чат.

Comment: Можете использовать апи для клиента ‍♀️